# th not indented at one cell

Tags: html, css

Is that possible not to indent cells in th? 
http://jsfiddle.net/kWTte/1/
HTML

```
<table>
    <th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of `th` as the equivalent of `td`, but for table's header.
So `th`s should be contained into a `tr` element.

The correct form is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header one</th>
        <th>Header two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

If you need to wrap the table header you could use `thead`. 
Similarly you could use `tbody` for the body of the table (note that you can have more than one tbody in the same table).